# Reload called page on each Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need a page called via ajax to fully reload everytime I request it. Currently, when requested for the first time it loads the page correctly, but when requested the second time it loads with the previous result and then after 2 or 3 second loads the new result.

I want it to show a loading image while it reloads the page into my div.

See code I'm using below:

```
$io('#load_order_preview').on('click', function(){

            var portfolioName       = $io("#portfolioName").val();
            var instrumentType      = $io("#instrumentType").val();
            var securityName        = $io("#securityName").val();
            var orderType           = $io("#orderType").val();
            var priceType           = $io("#priceType").val();
            var quantityRequested   = $io("#quantityRequested").val();
            var orderTermName       = $io("#orderTermName").val();
            var limitPrice          = $io("#limitPrice").val();
            var stockPrice          = $io("#stockPrice").val();
            var stopPrice           = $io("#stopPrice").val();

            var dataString = 'portfolioName='+ portfolioName + '&instrumentType=' + instrumentType + '&securityName=' + securityName + '&orderType=' + orderType + '&priceType=' + priceType + '&quantityRequested=' + quantityRequested + '&orderTermName=' + orderTermName + '&limitPrice=' + limitPrice + '&stopPrice=' + stopPrice;

             $io('#load_popup_modal_orderpreview').load(
                 'load-preview.php?' + dataString
             }).modal({
             backdrop: 'static',
             keyboard: false
             }).show();

        });
```

I'd really like some help to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove extra semicolumn from `backdrop: 'static',;`.

Comment: where is your ajax call?

Comment: I have removed the extra semi-colon and it still doesn't work and sorry I'm not using ajax. just regular jquery javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, not sure it will work for regular javascript,

```
     $io('#load_order_preview').on('click', function(){

var dataString = 'portfolioName='+ portfolioName + '&instrumentType=' + instrumentType + '&securityName=' + securityName
                    + '&orderType=' + orderType + '&priceType=' + priceType + '&quantityRequested=' + quantityRequested
                    + '&orderTermName=' + orderTermName + '&limitPrice=' + limitPrice + '&stopPrice=' + stopPrice;

                 $io('#load_popup_modal_orderpreview').load(
                     'load-preview.php?' + dataString
                 }).modal({
                 backdrop: 'static',
                 keyboard: false,
cache: false
                 }).show();

});
```

basically your problem is of cache, when you reload the page, it took values from cache and when you reload 2-3 times it fetch forcefully from server.

Edit ==

If cache is not your prob, and since it took 2-3 sec to reflect new images, it is prob with async behavior of browser. When you make request, browser will not wait for your response and move ahead, when it will receive response it will act on it.

Solution,

try to make ajax call and on success response do your activity

or

(last option and not good practice) 
Make your call async false,

```
 $io('#load_order_preview').on('click', function(){

var dataString = 'portfolioName='+ portfolioName + '&instrumentType=' + instrumentType + '&securityName=' + securityName
                    + '&orderType=' + orderType + '&priceType=' + priceType + '&quantityRequested=' + quantityRequested
                    + '&orderTermName=' + orderTermName + '&limitPrice=' + limitPrice + '&stopPrice=' + stopPrice;

                 $io('#load_popup_modal_orderpreview').load(
                     'load-preview.php?' + dataString
                 }).modal({
                 backdrop: 'static',
                 keyboard: false,
cache: false,
async: false
                 }).show();

});
```

note this will make your browser wait till your server respond to your call.

Comment: Hi the cache property didn't solve it. The problem is it eventually loads the correct figures after 2 - 3 seconds, but it displays the previous figures before loading the newly requested figures (which may confuse the user if they are impatient).I want it to at least show a loading image until the new figures are ready

Comment: could you fiddle it ?

Comment: may not be able to fiddle it. too many of my HTML is called dynamically. Lots of includes etc

Comment: Thanks man. Took your advice and it worked. see code below   $io('#load_popup_modal_orderpreview').load('load-preview.php?' + dataString,function(response, status){
                        if (status == "success"){
                            $io('#load_popup_modal_orderpreview').html(response).modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false}).show();
                        }
                });

Comment: welcome :) I've not used pure js call but fortunatelly able to suggest the solution.